# Is it possible to arrange github download files in folders?

Tags: github, release-management

I'm migrating a project from another system to github. We have many old releases as `.tar.gz` files. I want to migrate them to github for archival purposes. I intend to upload the old files as releases, not as items in the git. Is there a way to organize the uploads in folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it isn't. At least not today, on August 19, 2012.